# How to maintain rmap for Linux folio mapped as non-transparent huge page

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, huge-pages

#### Summary

Linux's (v6.0) [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v6.0/core-api/mm-api.html?highlight=folio#c.folio) for `struct folio` claims that

> It may be mapped into userspace at an address which is at an arbitrary page offset, ...

However, it does not seem to be possible to correctly maintain `rmap` for pages in the folio unless used as a transparent hugepage (THP), which implies that the userspace address is also aligned to the THP size. Is there a correct way to maintain `rmap` for folios which are not used for THP?

#### Detailed explanation

A folio is `a physically, virtually and logically contiguous set of bytes` with a `power-of-two` size ([kernel doc](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v6.0/core-api/mm-api.html?highlight=folio#c.folio)). The `struct folio` is the head of a compound page. As per [this](https://lwn.net/Articles/849538/) LWN article, the use of folios targets a particular issue, separating APIs which work on the head page of a compound page from those which work with all pages. Hugepages are one motivating usecase.

For example, consider a folio of order 2, with physical pages (`pfn`, `pfn+1`, `pfn+2`, `pfn+3`). This folio will be aligned to a 4-page boundary in physical address (`pfn & 0x3 == 0`), and in kernel virtual addresses.

As per the doc, the kernel allows a folio to be mapped at unaligned userspace virtual address (`vpn`, `vpn+1`, `vpn+2`, `vpn+3` where `vfn & 0x3 != 0`). This also implies that the use of a folio is not exclusively for THPs. Of course, when mapping `pfn` at `vpn`, I would also like to correctly maintain a `rmap`. In my use case, the folio is not a THP, and not the correct order for either a 2MB or 1GB hugepage.

However, the current `rmap` code seems to only work if folios are used for THPs. For example, `page_add_new_rmap` contains the following code:

```
void page_add_new_anon_rmap(struct page *page,
    struct vm_area_struct *vma, unsigned long address)
{
    const bool compound = PageCompound(page);
    int nr = compound ? thp_nr_pages(page) : 1;

    if (compound) {
        VM_BUG_ON_PAGE(!PageTransHuge(page), page);
        ....
    }
}
```

#### Questions

1. Is the current Linux implementation of `folio` and `rmap` only for THPs
2. Is there a "correct" way to map a folio while also maintaining the `rmap`?